# TextField moved up when covered by keyboard doesn't stay in position

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, textfield

I'm trying to solve common problem to move up TextField when it becomes covered with keyboard. Basically I have followed the Apple's documentation from [Moving Content That Is Located Under the Keyboard](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH5-SW7)

But I'm not using ScrollView just have two TextFileds inside main View.

Lower one moves up when it becomes covered with keyboard and works perfect on iPhones 8 or SE (with sharp screen corners, where main View and SafeArea are the same).

I have problem on iPhone X, XS or 11 (those with Face ID notch and rounded screen corners, where Safe Area and main View are not the same).

On these iPhones the **TextField initially moves up into desired position** but immediately after touching the keyboard (after typing a letter) just by it self it **jumps down by some pixels and hides again behind the keyboard**.

Here is the code I'm working on:

```swift
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  TextFields
//
//  Created by Manoli on 24/04/2020.
//  Copyright © 2020 macForce. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var upperTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var lowerTextField: UITextField!

    var activeTextField: UITextField?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        upperTextField.delegate = self
        lowerTextField.delegate = self

        registerForKeyboardNotifications()
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        activeTextField = nil
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        activeTextField = textField
    }

    func registerForKeyboardNotifications() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(_:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(_:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
    }

    @objc func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: NSNotification) {

        let keyboardSpacing: CGFloat = 8.0 // Standard value for spacing between keyboard and textfield

        guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo,
            let keyboardFrameValue = userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue
            else { return }

        let keyboardFrame = keyboardFrameValue.cgRectValue

        guard let activeTextFieldFrame = activeTextField?.frame else { return }

        let positionShift = activeTextFieldFrame.origin.y + activeTextFieldFrame.height - keyboardFrame.origin.y + keyboardSpacing

        if positionShift > 0 {
            view.frame.origin.y = -positionShift
        }
    }

    @objc func keyboardWillHide(_ notification: NSNotification) {
        view.frame.origin.y = 0
    }
}
```

Here I have [link to whole project](https://github.com/igielskv/TextFields) on GitHub.

Does anyone have an idea why this makes problems only on certain type of iPhone screen? Is there anything wrong with an idea I'm using in this code?

Thanks a lot for any advice or suggestion, have great day everyone.

**Update:**

I found if vertical constraints of TextFields are set against Superview and not against Safe Area it works fine (also on iPhones X and above). So I have now updated [project on GitHub](https://github.com/igielskv/TextFields) accordingly. (The only thing I don't like is that vertical constraints against Superview are not symmetrical and they don't look quite right on iPhones SE and 8 and bellow.)

**Update:**

Now trying different approach using container View bottom constraint and Safe Area difference to calculate moving TextFiled up in [usingConstraints](https://github.com/igielskv/TextFields/tree/usingConstraints) branch. It **works ok** for all possible screen types, **but does not animate** with keyboard.

*ToDo: Still have to figure out how to animate this constraint changes according to the keyboard.*

Comment: I've found the only screen size which is different is the 11Pro, even the 11Pro Plus is pretty much the same as the 6, 7, 8, X, XR, 11......

Answer (score 0):

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) 
{
    activeTextField = textField
}

func showLoginKeyBoard()
{
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
}

 @objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification)
{
    if activeTextField == upperTextField
    {
        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue
        {
            if self.view.frame.origin.y == 0
            {
                self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height
            }
        }
    }

    if activeTextField == lowerTextField
    {
        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue
        {
            if self.view.frame.origin.y == 0
            {
                self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height + 50
            }
        }
    }
}

func hideLoginKeyboard()
{
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)

    let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(
        target: self,
        action: #selector(UIViewController.keyboardWillHide))
    tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}

@objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification)
{
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(1), execute:
        {
            if self.view.frame.origin.y != 0
            {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0.0, animations:
                    {
                        self.view.frame.origin.y = 0
                })
            }
    })
}

func deregisterFromKeyboardNotifications()
{
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}

override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool)
{
    deregisterFromKeyboardNotifications()
}
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. I have tried your code but had to correct  textFieldShouldBeginEditing function it's suppose to return -> Bool. Also I guess you were thinking action: #selector(ViewController.keyboardWillHide) not UIViewController. When I gave it a try it doesn't seem to work better. lowerTextFiled also jumps down after tapping some letter on the keyboard on iPhones X and above, there is also extra black gap between keyboard and shifted view. Your code is moving view when upperTextFiled is active, it is not covered with keyboard and this way it's actually moved out of sight.

Comment: Yeah return (activeTextField != nil) for shouldBeginEditing. Change the +50 to -50 or even view.frame.height /8 or whatever the right amount is.

Comment: TextFields should move simultaneously unless they're constrained to different views. Place hideKeyboard() in didEndEditing.